# R multinomial distribution variance

Tags: r, covariance, variance, multinomial

In the code below, `p_hat` contains the MLE's of the probabilities for X1, X2 and X3 in the given data sample. According to the [multinomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution) page on Wikipedia, the covariance matrix for the estimated probabilities is calculated as below:

```
set.seed(102)
X <- rmultinom(n=1, size=100, prob =c(0.1,0.3,0.6))
p_hat <- X/sum(X)

# print covariance matrix
cov_matrix <- matrix(0, nrow=length(p_hat), ncol=length(p_hat))
rownames(cov_matrix) <- c("X1","X2","X3"); colnames(cov_matrix) <- c("X1","X2","X3");
for (r in 1: length(p_hat)){
  for (c in 1: length(p_hat)){
    if(r==c){cov_matrix[r,c] <- p_hat[r] * (1-p_hat[r])}
    else{cov_matrix[r,c] <- -p_hat[r] *p_hat[c]}
  }
}
```

Is this implementation correct?

Is there an R function that can produce this covariance matrix given `prob =c(0.1,0.3,0.6)` for a multinomial distribution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can even use `outer` and `diag` to get the same result

```
> p <- drop(p_hat)
> variance         <-  p*(1-p)
> covariance       <- -outer(p, p)
> diag(covariance) <-  variance
> covariance
       [,1]    [,2]    [,3]
[1,]  0.090 -0.0290 -0.0610
[2,] -0.029  0.2059 -0.1769
[3,] -0.061 -0.1769  0.2379
```